# Gitleak Scan - Avoid previous Commits

Tags: jenkins, gitleaks

My gitleaks scan reports are generating the History of the failure from previous Commits.
I've got those failures fixed.But still the previous histories are appearing in the gitleak scan report in jenkins. Can anyone have any idea on how to avoid the History of gitleak scan Failures?

Comment: How have you integrated gitleaks with your jenkins pipeline? If you can please help around this, I have been struggling to execute gitleaks through Jenkins pipeline to scan the source code

Answer (score 2):

there are several options:

1. remove leaks from the git history, e.g. using https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/
2. add `.gitleaks.toml` config, e.g.

```ini
add [rules.allowlist]
description = "ignore commits"
commits = [ "commit-A", "commit-B"]
```

3. or if applicable - to use `.gitleaksignore` file
   https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks#gitleaksignore